# Robot Cloning story, novel, or even a movie!

Tags: story-identification, robots

I am searching for a sci-fi story, novel, or even a movie that talks about the robot cloning concept. What made ​​me search for it is that I want to name a programming project of mine with a name of a robot that implements the robot cloning concept. Hope you guys helping me :)

EDIT: I find this type of machines, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-replicating_machine. My question is: is there any sci-fi story talks about this idea and featuring a character that uses it, which I can pick its name for my project :)

Comment: Are you asking for identification of one you've read/seen/heard of?  Or just asking, hoping that one exists?  And what do you mean by cloning; making a copy of a human? Or taking one robot and making copies of it.  The first is easy; it shows up in many Scifi novels, such as the 'Caves of Steel' by Asimov.  The second is a basic development principle; make one that works, then copy, not to mention one of the common ideas behind how nanobots would work.

Comment: I never read about it in a sci-fi story, AFAICR NASA has a technology of robots that can make copies of itself. I don't know if there is a popular sci-fi story that talks about this concept and has a popular character that I can use its name for my project.

Comment: Gotcha; see below -- I tried to answer both.  Robots that can self replicate, however, is an old idea.  There should be lots of ideas for you to pick from.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is falling into the 'Lists' category that is discouraged... We'll see, shortly, as the Close votes come in, if they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for a machine that is made as a clone of a Human, it's not that uncommon of a concept in SciFi; the easiest one that leaps to mind is [R. Daneel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daneel_Olivaw) from Asimov's Robots and Foundation novels.

If you are looking for machines that copy themselves, perhaps the most basic example works best; [Nanobots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanobot).  The basic concept for them usually (until people started thinking of the 'Gray Goo' possibility) involved them making copies of themselves, as needed, out of available materials.  This idea also shows up in the Macro scale, an example being in [Sheffield's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Sheffield) Proteus series, where space based machines do the same thing.

There are many more examples of both, but clarification as to which one you are looking for would help :)

---

*EDIT*  -- Ok, now knowing that you are looking for Machine copying... How about [Clifford Simak's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_D._Simak) 'Time and Again'?  It's a high level version, where you have basically chemically constructed humans (that are considered to be androids and close to robots, since they are man made) that develop a way to reproduce themselves without man's help?  Interesting story, bringing into question a lot about what defines life, spirit, etc.

The title 'Project Gray Goo' appeals to me, tho :)

Regardless.. I think [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_replicating_machine#Self-replicating_machines_in_fiction) will give you what you are looking for; the Wikipedia section on Self Replicating Machines in Fiction.  Or possibly this TvTropes link: [Recursive Creators](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RecursiveCreators)

Comment: It's really a cool story :), but what I needs is a name for a character that implements this self-replication method.

Comment: How about Agatha Heterodyne?  She created the 'Dingbots' in the Girl Genius cartoon, that replicate themselves?  Or, if you check those examples, a number of them include names, such as the Alien Series had the 'synthetics' that developed each other.

Comment: It's also a cool name, I am searching in the list of names now :) Thanks for this great answer.

Comment: One more for you; 'Von Neumann' is behind the machines bearing his name; self-replicating spacecraft.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_probe#Von_Neumann_probes